# Access SQL: Having clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to get a distinct count of users who have a repeat rate greater than one (in Excel for example I would use the countif formula to do this).

I am using Ms-access (2016) and can't seem to get this to work.  The results of the following query gives me the same results for the count of userName and Repeat Rate.

```
SELECT host, department, count([userName]) AS ['Distinct Users'], sum(Logins) AS ['Total Logins'], count([Repeat Rate]) AS ['Repeat Users']
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT department, [userName], host,[Repeat Rate], Logins FROM Sheet1)  AS x
GROUP BY department, host
ORDER BY host, department,
HAVING COUNT([Repeat Rate]) > 1;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

edit:

```
+------+----------+------------+-------------+--+
| host | username | Department | Repeat Rate |  |
+------+----------+------------+-------------+--+
| x    | Kyle     | D1         |           1 |  |
| x    | Max      | D1         |           4 |  |
| x    | Will     | D1         |           2 |  |
| x    | Will     | D1         |           2 |  |
+------+----------+------------+-------------+--+
```

With the above table for example, I would want it to say for host x in Department D1, there are 3 distinct users, and 2 users with a repeat rate greater than 1.

```
+------+------------+----------------+-------------+
| host | Department | Distinct Users | Repeat Rate |
+------+------------+----------------+-------------+
| x    | D1         |              3 |           2 |
+------+------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: `count(distinct [username])`  Distinct can be across an entire record when put at the beginning or just within a single column when used inside an aggregate function.  No need for subquery in my opinion if you  use this approach.  However sample data with expected results using that sample data would help clarify the question. https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ is a good way to present the data to SO once you have it in a HTML table, excel or other medium.

Comment: @xQbert I've tried the count(distinct[]) method before, but with microsoft access it doesn't seem to work..not sure why.  I've also added some tables, thanks for the advice!

Comment: "Kyle" has a rate of 1 only. That leaves 2 distinct users with a rate > 1. Not what your output sample shows ...

Comment: @Gustav That's what I'm looking for though - two columns. One to tell me distinct users (in terms of their name and regardless of repeat rate), and another based on repeat rate being greater than 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT host, department, count([userName]) AS ['Distinct Users'], sum(IIF([Repeat Rate]>1,1,0)) AS ['Repeat Users']
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT host, department, [userName], [Repeat Rate] FROM Sheet1)  AS x
GROUP BY department, host;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this:

```
SELECT x.host, x.department, max(users.unique_users) AS ['Distinct Users'], 
    sum(Logins) AS ['Total Logins'], max(repeats.unique_repeats) AS ['Repeat Users']
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT department, [userName], host,[Repeat Rate], Logins FROM Sheet1)  AS x
left join (select host, department, count(userName) as unique_users from (select distinct 
    host, department, [userName] from Sheet1)) as users on users.host = x.host and 
    users.department = x.department
left join (select host, department, count(userName) as unique_repeats 
    from (select distinct host, department, [userName] from Sheet1 where [Repeat Rate] > 1)) 
        as repeats on users.host = x.host and users.department = x.department
GROUP BY department, host
ORDER BY host, department;
```

Counting unique values is difficult in Access SQL. Normally you would use count(distinct var) as the other suggest, but that is not available to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the join you have shown in your post first part, but, considering your example only, the following query seems to resolve your problem

```
SELECT HOST, DEPARTMENT, SUM(DISTINCT_USER) AS DISTINCT_USER, MAX(CNT) AS REPEAT_RATE
FROM (
    SELECT HOST, DEPARTMENT, COUNT(DISTINCT USERNAME) AS DISTINCT_USER, REPEAT_RATE, COUNT(*) AS CNT
    FROM 
    GROUP BY HOST, DEPARTMENT, REPEAT_RATE
) A
GROUP BY HOST, DEPARTMENT
```